# Display None and Block reinforce CSS3 KeyframeAnimation in Webkit

Tags: css, webkit

In my html5 game I'm playing some css3 keyframe animations.
During the animation the user can press a pause button, which sets the div-container (containing children on which the animations are played) to display:none.
After getting back to gameplay and setting the div to `display:block`, the keyframeanimations are forced to get replayed in Chrome and Safari.
It works fine in Firefox!

I've created a jsfiddle to show the problem http://jsfiddle.net/rrDsN/ .
in firefox the element continues to rotate, in chrome and safari it gets replayed.

I tried to use `visibility:hidden, opacity:0` instead, but then I have problems with clickable elements (due to opacity) and visibility isn't recursive in the div-element.

How can i prevent the animation to get replayed in a webkit browser or what would be an alternative to display?

### Solution

It's a combination of zIndex and Opacity:
old code:

```
if(visible) {
            this.domEl.style.display='block';
        } else {
            this.domEl.style.display='none';
        }
```

new code:

```
if(visible) {
        this.domEl.style.zIndex=(this.prevZIndex==undefined?0:this.prevZIndex);
        this.domEl.style.opacity=1;
        console.log(this.name+" "+this.domEl.style.zIndex);
    } else {
        this.prevZIndex=this.domEl.style.zIndex;
        this.domEl.style.opacity=0;
        this.domEl.style.zIndex=-10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide by `position: absolute` with not visible coords ([`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/rrDsN/7/)):

```
document.getElementById('rotate').onmouseover = function(){
    this.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; top: -9999px;left: -9999px;';
};

document.getElementById('rotate').onmouseout = function(){
    this.removeAttribute('style');
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this trick! Unfortunately it didn't fit my needs perfectly, because I would also had to keep some of the elements clickable, some not.. display:none did solve that for me. The solution I found now was a combination of setting a negative z-Index and opacity! (see my first post) .. but thanks anyway :)